# Is there numeric value comparison available in Karate testing framework?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, karate

I gone through various [validation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation) and [Assertion](https://github.com/intuit/karate#payload-assertions) of karate framework. I did not found any functionality to compare numeric values in response. Below are some examples.

- 1.00 and 1.0 should be equal
- 1 and 1.00 are equal

Right now there is only string comparison, so above values are giving as not equal as they are different is string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course if you try to compare two strings, it will be different ! Karate handles numbers perfectly well, looks like you haven't read the documentation or examples properly.

```
* def a = 1
* def b = 1.0
* match a == b
```

If your JSON responses are coming as strings, and you really want to compare them as numbers, you need to convert them. Refer to the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#floats-and-integers

```
* def a = 1
* def b = '1.0'
* match a == b * 1
* match a == ~~b
```